# hat ^ symbol in grep argument

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have come across a script that is supposed to make adding a user to a linux system easier. I am fairly new to bash scripts so i am trying to figure out what each line of said script is doing. 
Now i am trying to find out what this part of the script means `"^$username"` what is the function of the `^` before the variable?

for some more context here is the part of the script this variable is in:

```
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
```

Comment: Reading the section on regular expressions in the `grep` manual will enlight you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a literal `^`. In this case, it's being passed to `egrep`, which takes extended regular expressions, a kind of way of specifying a pattern to match in a given string (kind of like globbing/wildcards, but much more powerful). `^` just means "This has to be at the start of the string/line". So in this case, it'll match every line in /etc/passwd that starts with the contents of the "username" variable.

(Note there's a potential bug here, because if there's a user rich and a user richard, typing the username rich will also match richard.)

Comment: Thanks @Muzer the following has removed the potential bug:
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1

Comment: @a.smith, if you only added checking of error code of `grep`, then it didn't solve a bug Muzer was talking about. You won't be able to add user 'rich', when you have a user 'richard'. Regexp is too wide here. Think about using `"^$username:"` - colon is used to separate fields in /etc/passwd, so it would match whole field as a username.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of a regular expression and just means "at beginning of line".

For a nice list on regular expressions, take a look at [grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html).